# Need to Add a Scroll Toolbar to FGCs LabelFrame (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Working on an internal app and trying to get a scrollbar to **"FGCs"** labelFrame only, in addition, I need to scale the frame to the app size.

I'll be happy if anyone could assist me in refactoring this and create the scrollbar.

I know that I need to create a canvas or something, but do not know how.

This is a first time for me with Tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
import os, subprocess
from tkinter import ttk

managment = ["MAIN","NAV","OUTPUT","OUTPUTSPARE","GATEWAY","Sync1","Sync2"]
servers = ["recon01","recon02","recon03","recon04","recon05","recon06","recon07","recon08","recon09","recon10","recon11","recon12","render01","render02","storinator"]
FGCs =["fgc01","fgc02","fgc03","fgc04","fgc05","fgc06","fgc07","fgc08","fgc09","fgc10","fgc11","fgc12","fgc13","fgc14","fgc15","fgc16","fgc17","fgc18","fgc19","fgc20","fgc21","fgc22","fgc23","fgc24","fgc25","fgc26","fgc27","fgc28","fgc29","fgc30","fgc31","fgc32","fgc33","fgc34","fgc35","fgc36","fgc37","fgc38","fgcspare1","fgcspare2","fgcspare3","fgcspare4"]
tests = ["Network", "GPU", "Time", "Gidel", "Snapshot", "Disks"]
testbuttons = []
serverbuttons = []
managebuttons = []
fgcbuttons = []


class mainwindow:
    global test    
    global testbuttons
    global managment
    global managebuttons
    global FGCs

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("System Report Tool")
        master.geometry("1000x500")

        self.Tests = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Tests")
        self.Tests.pack(expand="no",anchor=W,pady=20)

        for test in tests:
            testcheck = ttk.Checkbutton(self.Tests, text=test)
            testcheck.pack(side=LEFT, anchor="n")
            testbuttons.append(testcheck)

        def select_tests():
            for test in testbuttons:
                test.invoke()

        selecttests = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Select All",command=select_tests)
        selecttests.place(x=260,y=16)

        self.Managment = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Managment")
        self.Managment.configure(width=10, height=20)
        self.Managment.pack(expand="no",anchor=W)

        for manage in managment:
            managecheck = ttk.Checkbutton(self.Managment, text=manage)
            managecheck.pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")
            managebuttons.append(managecheck)

        def select_manage():
            for manage in managebuttons:
                manage.invoke()

        selectmanage = ttk.Checkbutton(self.Managment, text="Select All",command=select_manage)
        selectmanage.pack()

        self.FGCs = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="FGCs")
        self.FGCs.configure(width=10, height=20)
        self.FGCs.place(x=120,y=80)

        for fgc in FGCs:
            fgccheck = ttk.Checkbutton(self.FGCs, text=fgc)
            fgccheck.pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")
            fgcbuttons.append(fgccheck)

        def select_fgc():
            for fgc in fgcbuttons:
                fgc.invoke()

        selectfgc = ttk.Checkbutton(self.FGCs, text="Select All",command=select_fgc)
        selectfgc.pack()

root = Tk()
Window = mainwindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Scrollbar` doesn't work with `Frame`. You would have to search examples how to use `Canvas` with `Frame` to scroll it. It is so called `"ScrolledCanvas"` or `"ScrolledFrame"`

Comment: instead of using `global` you should create variables in class and use `self.`

Comment: examples for [scrolled-frame-canvas](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/scrolled-frame-canvas) on GitHub

Comment: I know that Scrollbar is not working on Frame. this is why I created this question.

Comment: I'll be happy if someone will be able to help me to find the solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy code with `class ScrolledFrame` from [scrolled-frame-canvas](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/scrolled-frame-canvas)

Create `ScrolledFrame` inside `LabelFrame` `self.FGCs`

```
self.sf = ScrolledFrame(self.FGCs)
self.sf.pack()
```

And then put widgets in `inner` element in `ScrolledFrame` instead of putting them in `self.FGCs` like

```
fgccheck = ttk.Checkbutton(self.sf.inner, text=fgc)
```

---

Working code

```
import os
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class ScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, vertical=True, horizontal=False):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # canvas for inner frame
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self._canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news') # changed

        # create right scrollbar and connect to canvas Y
        self._vertical_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self._canvas.yview)
        if vertical:
            self._vertical_bar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self._canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self._vertical_bar.set)

        # create bottom scrollbar and connect to canvas X
        self._horizontal_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command=self._canvas.xview)
        if horizontal:
            self._horizontal_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
        self._canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self._horizontal_bar.set)

        # inner frame for widgets
        self.inner = tk.Frame(self._canvas)
        self._window = self._canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.inner, anchor='nw')

        # autoresize inner frame
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed

        # resize when configure changed
        self.inner.bind('<Configure>', self.resize)

        # resize inner frame to canvas size
        self.resize_width = False
        self.resize_height = False
        self._canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.inner_resize)

    def resize(self, event=None): 
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox('all'))

    def inner_resize(self, event):
        # resize inner frame to canvas size
        if self.resize_width:
            self._canvas.itemconfig(self._window, width=event.width)
        if self.resize_height:
            self._canvas.itemconfig(self._window, height=event.height)

managment = ["MAIN","NAV","OUTPUT","OUTPUTSPARE","GATEWAY","Sync1","Sync2"]
servers = ["recon01","recon02","recon03","recon04","recon05","recon06","recon07","recon08","recon09","recon10","recon11","recon12","render01","render02","storinator"]
FGCs =["fgc01","fgc02","fgc03","fgc04","fgc05","fgc06","fgc07","fgc08","fgc09","fgc10","fgc11","fgc12","fgc13","fgc14","fgc15","fgc16","fgc17","fgc18","fgc19","fgc20","fgc21","fgc22","fgc23","fgc24","fgc25","fgc26","fgc27","fgc28","fgc29","fgc30","fgc31","fgc32","fgc33","fgc34","fgc35","fgc36","fgc37","fgc38","fgcspare1","fgcspare2","fgcspare3","fgcspare4"]
tests = ["Network", "GPU", "Time", "Gidel", "Snapshot", "Disks"]
testbuttons = []
serverbuttons = []
managebuttons = []
fgcbuttons = []

class mainwindow:
    global test    
    global testbuttons
    global managment
    global managebuttons
    global FGCs

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("System Report Tool")
        master.geometry("1000x500")

        self.Tests = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Tests")
        self.Tests.pack(expand="no", anchor=W, pady=20)

        for test in tests:
            testcheck = ttk.Checkbutton(self.Tests, text=test)
            testcheck.pack(side=LEFT, anchor="n")
            testbuttons.append(testcheck)

        def select_tests():
            for test in testbuttons:
                test.invoke()

        selecttests = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Select All",command=select_tests)
        selecttests.place(x=260,y=16)

        self.Managment = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Managment")
        self.Managment.configure(width=10, height=20)
        self.Managment.pack(expand="no",anchor=W)

        for manage in managment:
            managecheck = ttk.Checkbutton(self.Managment, text=manage)
            managecheck.pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")
            managebuttons.append(managecheck)

        def select_manage():
            for manage in managebuttons:
                manage.invoke()

        selectmanage = ttk.Checkbutton(self.Managment, text="Select All",command=select_manage)
        selectmanage.pack()

        self.FGCs = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="FGCs")
        self.FGCs.configure(width=10, height=20)
        self.FGCs.place(x=120, y=80)

        self.sf = ScrolledFrame(self.FGCs)
        self.sf.pack()

        for fgc in FGCs:
            fgccheck = ttk.Checkbutton(self.sf.inner, text=fgc)
            fgccheck.pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")
            fgcbuttons.append(fgccheck)

        def select_fgc():
            for fgc in fgcbuttons:
                fgc.invoke()

        selectfgc = ttk.Checkbutton(self.sf.inner, text="Select All",command=select_fgc)
        selectfgc.pack()

root = Tk()
Window = mainwindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** This code uses `pack()` with some options to resize widgets when window is resized

```
import os
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class ScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, vertical=True, horizontal=False):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # canvas for inner frame
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self._canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news') # changed

        # create right scrollbar and connect to canvas Y
        self._vertical_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self._canvas.yview)
        if vertical:
            self._vertical_bar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self._canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self._vertical_bar.set)

        # create bottom scrollbar and connect to canvas X
        self._horizontal_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command=self._canvas.xview)
        if horizontal:
            self._horizontal_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
        self._canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self._horizontal_bar.set)

        # inner frame for widgets
        self.inner = tk.Frame(self._canvas)
        self._window = self._canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.inner, anchor='nw')

        # autoresize inner frame
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed

        # resize when configure changed
        self.inner.bind('<Configure>', self.resize)

        # resize inner frame to canvas size
        self.resize_width = False
        self.resize_height = False
        self._canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.inner_resize)

    def resize(self, event=None): 
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox('all'))

    def inner_resize(self, event):
        # resize inner frame to canvas size
        if self.resize_width:
            self._canvas.itemconfig(self._window, width=event.width)
        if self.resize_height:
            self._canvas.itemconfig(self._window, height=event.height)

managment = ["MAIN","NAV","OUTPUT","OUTPUTSPARE","GATEWAY","Sync1","Sync2"]
servers = ["recon01","recon02","recon03","recon04","recon05","recon06","recon07","recon08","recon09","recon10","recon11","recon12","render01","render02","storinator"]
FGCs =["fgc01","fgc02","fgc03","fgc04","fgc05","fgc06","fgc07","fgc08","fgc09","fgc10","fgc11","fgc12","fgc13","fgc14","fgc15","fgc16","fgc17","fgc18","fgc19","fgc20","fgc21","fgc22","fgc23","fgc24","fgc25","fgc26","fgc27","fgc28","fgc29","fgc30","fgc31","fgc32","fgc33","fgc34","fgc35","fgc36","fgc37","fgc38","fgcspare1","fgcspare2","fgcspare3","fgcspare4"]
tests = ["Network", "GPU", "Time", "Gidel", "Snapshot", "Disks"]
testbuttons = []
serverbuttons = []
managebuttons = []
fgcbuttons = []

class mainwindow:
    global test    
    global testbuttons
    global managment
    global managebuttons
    global FGCs

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("System Report Tool")
        master.geometry("1000x500")

        # --- top ---

        self.Tests = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Tests")
        self.Tests.pack(anchor='w', pady=20)

        for test in tests:
            testcheck = ttk.Checkbutton(self.Tests, text=test)
            testcheck.pack(side='left', anchor="n")
            testbuttons.append(testcheck)

        def select_tests():
            for test in testbuttons:
                test.invoke()

        selecttests = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Select All",command=select_tests)
        selecttests.place(x=260,y=16)

        # --- middle ---

        self.Managment = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Managment")
        self.Managment.configure(width=10, height=20)
        self.Managment.pack(anchor='nw', side='left')

        for manage in managment:
            managecheck = ttk.Checkbutton(self.Managment, text=manage)
            managecheck.pack(anchor="w")
            managebuttons.append(managecheck)

        def select_manage():
            for manage in managebuttons:
                manage.invoke()

        selectmanage = ttk.Checkbutton(self.Managment, text="Select All",command=select_manage)
        selectmanage.pack()

        self.FGCs = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="FGCs")
        self.FGCs.configure(width=10, height=20)
        self.FGCs.pack(fill='y', expand=True, side='left', anchor='w')

        self.sf = ScrolledFrame(self.FGCs)
        self.sf.pack(fill='y', expand=True)

        for fgc in FGCs:
            fgccheck = ttk.Checkbutton(self.sf.inner, text=fgc)
            fgccheck.pack(anchor="w")
            fgcbuttons.append(fgccheck)

        def select_fgc():
            for fgc in fgcbuttons:
                fgc.invoke()

        selectfgc = ttk.Checkbutton(self.sf.inner, text="Select All", command=select_fgc)
        selectfgc.pack()


root = Tk()
Window = mainwindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: only one question, why is the scrollbar and frame are not changing with the app resize?

Comment: scrollbar is inside `FGCs` which uses `place()` to put it in window - and `place()` never resize widget. You would have to use `self.FGCs.pack(fill='y', expand=True)` and it will resize `FGC` in window automatically. And then you need also `self.sf.pack(fill='y', expand=True)` to resize `ScrollbarFrame` inside `FGCs` automatically. But it will also move "FGC" so it may need `pack(..., side='left', anchor='w')`

Comment: I added code with some changes. You can use tools like [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) to compare both versions and see what was changed.